# IE "Style Calculation" performance incredibly slow in AngularJS app

Tags: css, angularjs, performance, internet-explorer

I have an AngularJS app using Angular Material and data loaded from an external API.

THere is nothing particularly groundbreaking with this app, and all of my tests run absolutely fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

However, when I use Internet Explorer, all hell breaks loose. The app is incredibly slow, CSS animations are painfully laggy, the app is completely unusable.

I've spent the day trying a number of potential bugfixes and debugging, but I'm coming up trumps.

Things that I can see:

- When I use IE11's Developer Tools and run a performance log, "Style Calculations" take up, by far, the most amount of time.
- When I have wildcard CSS selectors performance is slower (like `*{box-sizing: border-box}`)

Here's the output from the performance inspector, when literally all I do is scroll down an `md-virtual-repeat`:

[image: IE Performance: Style Calculation]

As you can see, `style calculation` is taking up a whole lot of time here.

Googling has come up trumps with workarounds for this. What's going on here? Is this a red herring, and the issue is somewhere else in my app (my JS is as efficient as I can think of making it, and I've also tested loading in no real data, just 30 static objects into the virtual repeater - and results are the same).

Comment: I heard that those material design css and its selectors are slow on IE.

Comment: I have a similar issue with ngMaterial 1.0.7 in IE11 too. When intl-tel-input and angular-material combine, every time I scroll the country list with phone number country codes, it takes 750ms to render each scroll. It's beyond ridiculous, and every other browser works fine. If you find solution, please ping me. Right now I'm reviewing CSS, commenting-out some CSS and noticing slight speed improvements, but overall still really slow and lagging.

Comment: @ngDeveloper The solution was to (a) upgrade to the latest ngMaterial, I think it was RC2, and (b) IE was being overloaded by the amount of CSS I had. Deleting some of the CSS libraries that were being used had a pretty big impact on the site speed.

Comment: @Jascination, thanks. I tried 1.1.0-rc4 yesterday and the material team seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: @ngDeveloper Awesome - just upgraded to RC5 and it makes a world of difference in IE11. My app went from being unusable in IE to perfectly fine - still not as fast as Chrome but acceptable. You made my day!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with a "Style Calculations" taking about 700ms while scrolling and loading CPU to 100% (IE11, Win10)

In my particular case it was caused by the CSS rule that contained a "+ " selector, e.g.

```
.menu li + li a {border: 0}
```

After removing it - works fine.

Hope it saves someone couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, as @ngDeveloper points out in a comment is to upgrade ngMaterial. I had this problem, and it was positionElements that was causing the problem for me.